# Is it possible to use devextreme with create-react-app without ejecting?

Tags: create-react-app, devextreme

TL;DR: Is it possible to use devextreme in an application created with create-react-app without ejecting?

1. I created an app using create-react-app.
2. I `npm install`ed devextreme
3. Next step according to the [manual](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-react#installation) is webpack configuration, which can't really be done without ejecting from create-react-app.

Is there a way around this?